# Process to convert TObjectlist to TObjectList<T> to use in TObjectDataset

Tags: delphi, dataset, spring4d

I would like to use TObjectDataset which relies on TObjectList<> (System.Generics.Collections / Spring.Collections) but only have a TObjectList (System.Contnrs). Is there any way besides for iterating through objects and building a new TObjectList<> to get this working? Ultimately I would like to couple the TObjectList to an Objectdataset in order to bind to an UI.

Comment: Switch to using the type that the library requires and the problem vanishes

Comment: Would like to but data is from json via orm that only supports system. Contents. Tobjectlist and not generics. Hence the approach above.... Seems so close

Comment: Maybe find an ORM system that fits better with the rest of your code

Comment: Thanks trialed a few there's always a trade off somewhere though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is slightly wrong. The Spring4d TObjectDataSet takes an `IObjectList` interface which is a specialization of `IList<T>` where `T` is `TObject`.

This contract is matched by the `Contnrs.TObjectList`. So "simply" create a wrapper class for your `TObjectList` that implements `IObjectList`. I put simply in quotes because this interface has quite a lot of methods. You can use `TListBase<T>` as base class for your adapter which already has all methods implemented. Then you only need to override a few (take a look at `TList<T>` which ones those are).

One important detail to know is that the `TObjectDataSet` needs to know the exact class of the objects in your list. This is done via the `ElementType` property of the `IObjectList`. If that returns `TObject` though this is not very helpful. So you need to override that method.

Edit: Here is the full code of such an adapter class:

```
unit Spring.Collections.ObjectListAdapter;

interface

uses
  Contnrs,
  TypInfo,
  Spring.Collections,
  Spring.Collections.Base;

type
  TObjectListAdapter = class(TListBase<TObject>, IObjectList)
  private
    fList: TObjectList;
    fClassType: TClass;
  protected
    function GetCapacity: Integer; override;
    function GetCount: Integer; override;
    function GetElementType: PTypeInfo; override;
    function GetItem(index: Integer): TObject; override;
    procedure SetCapacity(value: Integer); override;
    procedure SetItem(index: Integer; const value: TObject); override;
  public
    constructor Create(const list: TObjectList; classType: TClass);

    procedure Delete(index: Integer); override;
    function Extract(const item: TObject): TObject; override;
    procedure Insert(index: Integer; const item: TObject); override;

    procedure Exchange(index1, index2: Integer); override;
    procedure Move(currentIndex, newIndex: Integer); override;
  end;

implementation

uses
  Classes,
  Types;

{ TObjectListAdapter }

constructor TObjectListAdapter.Create(const list: TObjectList; classType: TClass);
begin
  inherited Create;
  fList := list;
  fClassType := classType;
end;

procedure TObjectListAdapter.Delete(index: Integer);
begin
  fList.Delete(index);
end;

procedure TObjectListAdapter.Exchange(index1, index2: Integer);
begin
  fList.Exchange(index1, index2);
end;

function TObjectListAdapter.Extract(const item: TObject): TObject;
begin
  Result := fList.Extract(item);
end;

function TObjectListAdapter.GetCapacity: Integer;
begin
  Result := fList.Capacity;
end;

function TObjectListAdapter.GetCount: Integer;
begin
  Result := fList.Count;
end;

function TObjectListAdapter.GetElementType: PTypeInfo;
begin
  Result := fClassType.ClassInfo;
end;

function TObjectListAdapter.GetItem(index: Integer): TObject;
begin
  Result := fList[index];
end;

procedure TObjectListAdapter.Insert(index: Integer; const item: TObject);
begin
  fList.Insert(index, item);
end;

procedure TObjectListAdapter.Move(currentIndex, newIndex: Integer);
begin
  fList.Move(currentIndex, newIndex);
end;

procedure TObjectListAdapter.SetCapacity(value: Integer);
begin
  fList.Capacity := value;
end;

procedure TObjectListAdapter.SetItem(index: Integer; const value: TObject);
begin
  fList[index] := value;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Thanks for that! Much appreciated. I added fClassType := classType; to the constructor.

Comment: Is it possible to make the implementation strongly typed rather than using TObject, essentially a generics based adapter like TObjectListAdapte<T> still retaining functionality introduced by TListBase though.

Comment: Sure you can make it `TObjectListAdaper<T: class> = class(TListBase<T>)`. But then you need to use `as IObjectList` because you cannot directly implement it.

Comment: Thanks Stefan I implemented as suggested but I want to use it in a 'provider' class but get an error E2010 Incompatible types: 'TItem' and 'TObject'  in XE2  **code next**     unit Test;

interface

uses
 SysUtils, Classes, System.Contnrs,
 System.Generics.Defaults, System.Generics.Collections, ObjectListAdapter, Spring.Collections;

type
  TItem = class
  end;
  TProvider = class
  public
    function Get: TPHSTObjectListAdapter<TItem>;
  end;

implementation

{ TClient }

function TProvider.Get: TPHSTObjectListAdapter<TItem>;
begin

end;

end.

Comment: Think I resolved it... GetItem and Extract method of TObjectListAdapter<T> was not cast as T hence TObject related error. Changed and working now:) Many Thanks again Stefan... I am loving spring4d and have barely scratched the surface:)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way besides for iterating through objects and building a new `TObjectList<T>` to get this working?

There is not. The two types are not compatible.

Comment: @TheBitman It is the answer to the question that was asked though. Sometimes the answer is that it is not possible.