# Spring4d - ObjectDataset refresh does not get records from underlying IObjectList

Tags: delphi, spring4d

I am using Spring4d `TObjectDataset` with a custom `IObjectList` adapter derived from `TListBase<TObject>`. I used [this SOA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43041651/3211143) as a base, though it uses a `TObjectList` and I use a `TCollection`.

I set the `TObjectDataset.Datalist` property to a new instance of this adapter. But if I add entries **directly into the underlying TCollection**, and hit `TObjectDataset.Refresh`, it seems the `TObjectDataset` will not query the underlying `TCollection` for new records (it does not query the `GetCount` procedure).Though, if I do `TObjectDataset.Close` then `TObjectDataset.Open`, the new record is shown.

Is there a mechanism in the `TObjectDataset` to refresh the entries?

I thought of implementing the `INotifyCollectionChanged<T>` interface on my custom `TCollection` class. The `IObjectList` adapter would subscribe to change notifications, updating itself. But maybe there is a builtin way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Set the `TrackChanges` property to `True`. This causes the ODS to add an OnChanged handler to the list.

If you are adding items to a list that does not notify any changes to the adapter though you are out of luck and need to either add to the adapter list or solve it differently.

P.S.: Could be `TObjectDataSet.InternalRefresh` is missing an inherited call - try that out.